# java running and editing at same time to debug

Tags: java, debugging, edit

I want to know if I can do such a thing: run and edit the program at the same time, I mean when I run my program, pause it and fix the problem and start at the point that I paused.
I saw a video on youtube called "coding with notch" and he was using a way to do this.

EDIT: can I edit the code in the same class as main? I tried it and it didn't work, if it works please say how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "hot code replacement", and Eclipse gives you this out-of-the-box. When you save your file, Eclipse compiles your changes automatically and makes sure your running program uses the new classfiles. No need to pause your program to make this happen, it all happens automatically behind the scenes.

Just make sure you enable `Project -> Build Automatically`.

Answer (score 4):

You might be referring to this:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F